# Android P: "smart text selection" like spotify

Tags: android

[image]

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/05/09/android-ps-new-recents-ui-includes-smart-text-selection-image-sharing-pulling-text-images/

how is this done?

Where can I find programming ressources?

I didnt find it here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0

And if its an action, I cant identify a "built in intent" for selecting "The Killers" ...

https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/

Comment: Did you find the answers for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/). At the moment they are not generally available for anyone to develop.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/

but which intent are they using from this list?